# Decay of Eigenfunctions for the 1D Discrete Random Schrodinger Operators

Tags: pr.probability, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Consider the operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ 
$$
H = \Delta + v.
$$ Here $\Delta$ is the nearest neighbour Laplacian on $\mathbb{Z}$, $\Delta_{k, \ell} =1 $ if $|k - \ell| =1 $ and zero otherwise, while $v_\ell , \ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ are independent identically distributed random variables with common distribution $\mu$.

If supp$\mu$ is bounded than we have the phenomenon of Anderson localization; with probability one, the spectrum of $H$ is pure point and the $\ell^2$-eigenvectors are exponentially localized. Focusing on the localization of the eigenvectors, this means that if $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $H$ then there exists $A, B  >0 $ such that
$$
\psi(k) \leq A \exp\left(-B|k| \right)
$$

I was wondering if there are explicit bounds on $B$? I've been looking for papers that discuss the ${rate}$ of decay of eigenvectors for RSO but I haven't been able to find anything.

The proof of localization that I've seen relies on the fact that for every fixed $E \in \mathbb{R}$ the Lyapunov exponent $\gamma(E)$ of the corresponding transfer matrix is non-zero almost surely. Is it true that the rate of decay of an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $E$ is bounded by $\gamma(E)$?

Thank you for any help or sources you can point me to.

Comment: Your last paragraph is correct, in the following sense: Fix $E$. Then $|\psi(n)|\lesssim e^{-\gamma |n|}$ almost surely. Note, however, that this on its own does not imply that almost surely, we have exponential decay for eigenvalues $E$ (this needs to be proved separately).

Comment: Thanks! Does this follow just from the fact that the Lyapunov exponent of the transfer matrix is non-zero? In other words, if I knew that with probability one, the Lyapunov exponent is non-zero Lebesgue almost everywhere, would this imply the exponential decay for all eigenvectors?

Comment: No, positive Lyapunov exponent will not give this. By Fubini, you obtain that almost surely, for almost all $E$ you have exponential decay, but the (singular) spectral measure could be supported on the exceptional set.

Comment: A reference you might useful (or not, it's not exactly what you asked) is http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/250.pdf (see Section 7 especially).

Comment: Right. This would just give that there is no absolutely continuous part of the spectral measure.

Comment: Great. I'll take a look at that reference. I'm also just wondering if it's a quick step from knowing that for a fixed eigenvalue $E$, a positive Lyapunov exponent implies that the corresponding eigenfunction is exponentially decaying. Is this just the Ruelle-Osceledec theorem?

Comment: Yes, Oseledec sounds like the kind of ingredient that's needed here.